# How to clear routing without moving to another page Flutter Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I can go to my page `PgMain` by a lot of way (end of action, logout, button go to menu, button back, system back button, etc.). I want clear my routing every time, where I open `PgMain` page. How to do it inside `PgMain` class, for example inside `build` method? As I said previously, I have a lot of ways to go to `PgMain`, and not at every case I can use `Get.offAll()` method

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Get.offAll(PgMain()); Get.off(PgMain());`

whenever you navigate to PgMain page.

Comment: Ok, I know that way, but how I can erase whole trace when I just see final view?
What I can add to `PgMain` page, not in page which redirected to `PgMain`

Comment: Any idea how to do it inside of `PgMain` class?